# RHbase/thrift install issue

Tags: r, hadoop, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install RHbase onto R 3.1.1 on Mac OSX 10.10.

I've installed thrift via Homebrew, and yet, I get the following when I try to install Hbase from source through R:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/rhbase_1.2.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package ‘rhbase’ ...
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include   -I. -g  -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -fpermissive -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I./gen_cpp `pkg-config --cflags thrift` -Wall -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c Hbase.cpp -o Hbase.o
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
In file included from Hbase.cpp:7:
./Hbase.h:10:10: fatal error: 'TProcessor.h' file not found
#include <TProcessor.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Hbase.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rhbase’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rhbase’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘/Users/halloran/Downloads/rhbase_1.2.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Presumably it's missing a link to the required library?

EDIT: Looking at what pkg-config returns..

```
pkg-config --cflags thrift
-I/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.1/include
```

Comment: Alas, no! Not tried fixing it since then, I must admit.

Answer (score 8):

I think I figured it out.  My config starts out the same as yours, and I get the same errors:

```
% pkg-config --cflags thrift
-I/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.2/include
```

I made two changes to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/thrift.pc`:

```
% cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
% perl -pi -e 's{(^includedir=.*/include$)}{$1/thrift}' thrift.pc
% perl -pi -e 's{(^Cflags:.*)}{$1 -std=c++11}' thrift.pc
```

The first one just adds `/thrift` to the end of the `includedir=` line.  The second adds the `-std=c++11` argument to `Cflags`, to solve the next problem you'll hit, a namespace issue.

Then your config should look like the below, and installing `rhbase` should succeed, though still with a lot of warnings.

```
% pkg-config --cflags thrift
-std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.2/include/thrift
```

Comment: Alas, no! 

    `Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rhbase/libs/rhbase.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rhbase/libs/rhbase.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN6apache6thrift9transport7TSocketC1ENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEi
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rhbase/libs/rhbase.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted`

Comment: 1000 times thanks for this! The problem with `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` was driving me crazy. Do you have any idea why it ended like that? Shouldn't it normally end in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/thrift`?

Comment: Thanks! It helped.